# call Javascript functions in webview from react-native

Tags: react-native, webview

I have two functions (setColor , setBackgroundColor) in my webview, which I want to call them. so this is my HTML page :

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function setColor() {
        alert('set color...')
    }

    function setBackgroundColor() {
        alert('set background color ...')
    }
</script>

</html>
```

React-native Webview

```
<WebView
        injectedJavaScript={
                    `....HERE....How can I call those functions`
        }
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
/>
```

**NOTE**: I know that with the help of `injectedJavaScript` I can make communication, but here I have two functions and I do not know
How call them?

Thanks in advance.
any help would be appreciated.